# A circular @Import has been detected

Tags: spring, spring-boot

- I have created spring-boot auto-configuration library few months before using spring-boot version `1.3.0.RC1`.

Its structure is:

### Core library

It contains @Configuration class that scans components within the library.

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
public class CoreLibAutoConfiguration {

}
```

### Library created using above (core) library.

It contains another @Configuration class. Its definition is

```
@Configuration
@Import(CoreLibAutoConfiguration.class)
@ComponentScan
public class MyLibAutoConfiguration {

}
```

It also contains `spring.factories` in its classpath. Which holds entry to auto-configure this library on application startup.

`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=MyLibAutoConfiguration`

---

Now I have integrated this library to my spring-boot web application which again uses the same spring-boot version `1.3.0.RC1`.

Everything worked as expected.

But, now am developing another spring-boot web application which uses spring-boot version `1.3.5.RELEASE`.

I tried to integrated the same library I have created before few months to my new web application. But I am failing with an error related to circular reference. The stacktrace is

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: A circular @Import has been detected: Illegal attempt by @Configuration class 'MyLibAutoConfiguration' to import class 'MyLibAutoConfiguration' as 'MyLibAutoConfiguration' is already present in the current import stack [MyLibAutoConfiguration->Application]
Offending resource: class path resource [mylib/MyLibAutoConfiguration.class]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:70) ~[spring-beans-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:475) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:278) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:191) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:510) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:278) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:232) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:510) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processDeferredImportSelectors(ConfigurationClassParser.java:455) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:186) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:321) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:243) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:273) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:98) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:678) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:520) ~[spring-context-4.2.6.RELEASE.jar:4.2.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:118) ~[spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:766) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.createAndRefreshContext(SpringApplication.java:361) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1191) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1180) [spring-boot-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at myapp.Application.main(Application.java:15) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.boot.maven.AbstractRunMojo$LaunchRunner.run(AbstractRunMojo.java:478) [spring-boot-maven-plugin-1.3.5.RELEASE.jar:1.3.5.RELEASE]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.8.0_45]
```

If I change the version of spring-boot to `1.3.0.RC1` for my new application, its again works fine.

I searched for the reason behind it and found a post https://jira.spring.io/browse/SPR-13101. It says its due to nesting of configuration classes.

Can anybody guide me about the proper solution for my issue ?

Answer (score 4):

As a fix I have updated my configurations for my auto-configuring library.

The steps I followed are:

- Remove `@Import` for `CoreLibAutoConfiguration`
- Add `CoreLibAutoConfiguration` to auto-configure using `spring.factories`
- `MyLibAutoConfiguration` should be initialized after `CoreLibAutoConfiguration` is initialized.

Finally code will be:

**MyLibAutoConfiguration**

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan
@AutoConfigureAfter(value = {CoreLibAutoConfiguration.class})    
public class MyLibAutoConfiguration {

}
```

**spring.factories**

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration=\
CoreLibAutoConfiguration,\
MyLibAutoConfiguration
```

And it works fine for me.